# Can trigger.io barcode scan module be used with RedLaser

Tags: trigger.io

We really like the Redlaser API. Is it possible to integrate trigger's barcode module with Redlaser?

Comment: This should be possible using a native plugin, have you check the docs here? http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/index.html#native-plugins